# swing trouble in designing the UI programmatically

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am new to swing but familiar to android and java. I have to design a UI in eclipse but programmatically without using any drag and drop functionality.I have no idea of how to design this though I have gone through the official site for this .. but I don't know what layout to choose, how to add the buttons, text fields and layouts .. exactly at same place .. 
This is my code...

LoginScreen.java

```
public class LoginScreen extends ContextBeanFactory {
LoginScreen(){
        frame.add(loginWindow());
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
     private Component loginWindow() {

        FmsJPanel panel  = new FmsJPanel();
panel.add(lblUsername);
        lblUsername.setBounds(100, 220, 100, 50);
        panel.add(txtFldUserName);

        txtFldPassword.setBounds(120,240,120,70);



        panel.add(lblPassword);        
        panel.add(txtFldPassword);
        panel.add(btnLogin);
btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           // action performed
}
private FmsJLabel lblUsername = new FmsJLabel(getMessage(Messages.USERNAME));
    private FmsJLabel lblPassword = new FmsJLabel(getMessage(Messages.PASSWORD));
    private FmsJTextField txtFldUserName = new FmsJTextField();
    private FmsJTextField txtFldPassword = new FmsJTextField();
    private FmsJButton btnLogin =  new FmsJButton(getMessage(Messages.LOGIN));
    private FmsJFrame frame = new FmsJFrame(getMessage(Messages.PROJECT_TITLE));

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     new LoginScreen();
    }

}
```

But this code is showing screen the way it wanted and I don't even know which layout choose. Please help me with hints or something you can .. 
My desired Layout[image]

Comment: Break your design into separate areas and use different layout managers to achieve your results

Comment: different layout likes ??

Comment: which layout shall i choose for the whole frame

Comment: BorderLayout, GridLayout and GridBagLayout

Answer (score 3):

I would choose GridBagLayout with constraints like this

```
THIS IS MY TITLE
x=0,y=0, width=3 height 1

The Box
x=0,y=1, width=1 height 3 fill=BOTH

User name label
x=1,y=1, width=1 height 1

User name field
x=2,y=1, width=1 height 1 fill=HORIZONTAL

Password label
x=1,y=2, width=1 height 1

Password field
x=2,y=2, width=1 height 1 fill=HORIZONTAL

Login button
x=2,y=3, width=1 height 1
```

UPDATE: Of course there should be proper anchors and fill weights for x and y

Comment: sir can u explain in very short , the basic functioning of GridBagLayout

Comment: thanks for your help .. i used the setBound() method